# how to get array data with in loop in php

Tags: php

```
$a = 1;
$b = 1;
while($a <= 4) {
    $main_marks = array();

    while($b <= 4) {
        $main_marks[] = 50;
        $b++;
    }

    print_r($main_marks);
    $a++;
}
```

The output what I got from that code is:

```
Array (
    [0] => 50
    [1] => 50
    [2] => 50
    [3] => 50
)
Array ()
Array ()
Array ()
```

But I want all the array variables with values.
help me out please.

Comment: What with array with values? Can you post your expected output?

Comment: you are pushing 50 in `$main_marks` , ` $main_marks[] = 50;` what do you expect ?

Comment: put `$b=1;` inside outer `while` loop?

Comment: I want the output like: Array ( [0] => 50 [1] => 50 [2] => 50 [3] => 50 ) Array ([0] => 50 [1] => 50 [2] => 50 [3] => 50 ) Array ([0] => 50 [1] => 50 [2] => 50 [3] => 50 ) Array ([0] => 50 [1] => 50 [2] => 50 [3] => 50 )  instead of Array ( [0] => 50 [1] => 50 [2] => 50 [3] => 50 ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( )

Comment: you will get Array ( [0] => 50 [1] => 50 [2] => 50 [3] => 50 ) Array ([0] => 50 [1] => 50 [2] => 50 [3] => 50 ) like this only. Only two because 'a' & 'b' are there

Comment: I just only want to get the data in array variable through out the every iteration of the loop.

Comment: You have `$b=1;` outside the loop, so that it reaches "4" while filling up first array. You need to put `$b=1;` after `while($a <= 4) {` i.e. reset it before filling an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create variable out side the loop.

```
$a = 1;
$b = 1;
$main_marks = array();
while($a <= 4) {


    while($b <= 4) {
        $main_marks[] = 50;
        $b++;
    }

    print_r($main_marks);
    $a++;
}
```

Comment: @LoveChaudhary Did you want 1 array with 16 values or 4 arrays with 4 values?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $a=0;
 $b=0;
 while($a < 4) {
     $b = 0;
     while($b < 4) {
       $main_marks[$a][$b] = 50;
       $b++;
     }

     $a++;
 }
 print_r($main_marks);
```

You want to fill a multidimensional array for your expected output.

Comment: its not working, still I got empty array output, please give some other method to solve that code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$main_marks = array();
for($a=0;$a<4;$a++)
{
  for($b=0;$b<4;$b++)
  {
    $main_marks[$a][$b]=50;
  }
}
print_r($main_marks);
?>

Output:
Array
([0] => Array ( [0] => 50 [1] => 50 [2] => 50 [3] => 50 )
[1] => Array ( [0] => 50 [1] => 50 [2] => 50 [3] => 50 )
[2] => Array ( [0] => 50 [1] => 50 [2] => 50 [3] => 50 )
[3] => Array ( [0] => 50 [1] => 50 [2] => 50 [3] => 50 ) )
```

Comment: My Code Worked Or Not @LoveChaudhary ?

Answer (score 0):

Put `$b=1;` inside outer loop:

```
$a=1;
while($a <= 4) {
    $b=1;
    $main_marks = array();

    while($b <= 4) {
        $main_marks[] = 50;
        $b++;
    }

    print_r($main_marks);
    $a++;
}
```

Now you reset `$b` counter for each array